# How angular compiler interpret Pipe when we use in html?

Tags: angular, filter, compiler-construction, pipe

I know how to use pipe in angular ts file or in html file to filter data.
But i dont understand how angular compiler interpret our pipe when we use it in our html file.
How does it attach pipe class object in view of component?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity i'll start with an example, We have an array of strings and we want to apply a pipe to shorten its sentences or strings

```
myArray= ['HereISTheFirstString' , 'HereISTheSecondString' , 'HereISTheThirdString']
```

So we're going to create a new file let's call `shorten.pipe.ts`, Inside the file

```
import { PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'shorten'
})
export class ShortenPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: any) {
     return value.substr(0 , 12) + '...';
    }
}
```

To use it you have to add to declarations array in `app.module.ts`,
Now we need to use it inside our HTML page

```
<div *ngFor="let str of myArray">
   <h3> {{ str | shorten }} </h3>
<div>
```

So how actually it works , It works whenever the compiler sees `shorten` which we define it in `@Pipe({ name: 'shorten' })`-You can call it whatever-,It will call transform function and pass string as a value to it and return the result.

You can also pass pramaters to transform function like

```
   transform(value: any, limit: number) {
     if(value.length > limit)
        return value.substr(0 , limit) + '...';
      return value;
    }
```

And for HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let str of myArray">
   <h3> {{ str | shorten: 10 }} </h3>
<div>
```

For `:` After shorten pipe it's accept a parameter which indicates how out string shall be limited, So whenever a `:` it's a param.

Another something in Pipes working

## Chaining Pipes

A simple example for showing how a sequence of pipes works

```
<div>
{{ yourDate | date:'fullDate' | uppercase }}
</div>
```

It will go from left to right and applying different pipes.

I hope you can find this useful.

Comment: Abdul,this is functinality of pipe ..I know it,and are you sure ...."So how actually it works , It works whenever the compiler sees shorten which we define it in @Pipe({ name: 'shorten' })-You can call it whatever-,It will call transform function and pass string as a value to it and return the result."..compiler calls transform function?beacuse compilation is one time process..and every time i make any change ..change detection kicks in..and transform function is again called...I am not sure for compiler part of your answer.

Comment: My question is jsut like change detector object attaached to view ,,do we have any pipe class object attached to view?

Comment: I cite the following from Angular formal website
"Pipes and change detection: 
Angular looks for changes to data-bound values through a change detection process that runs after every DOM event: every keystroke, mouse move, timer tick, and server response. This could be expensive. Angular strives to lower the cost whenever possible and appropriate.

Angular picks a simpler, faster change detection algorithm when you use a pipe."

Comment: In another word Angular executes an impure pipe during every component change detection cycle. what an impure pipe means ? 
it is like a normal pip but called most of the time,In every keystroke or mouse-move.